# Rewriting WPF GridViewColumn alignment in a less verbose way

Tags: wpf, xaml

I wanted just to right align one column in WPF and I found out that the syntax is not exactly syntetic... Is there a way to make it more syntetic?

Consider that this one colum, but I have 20 columns which share the same identical structure, changing only the displayed property.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="trial" Width="110">
 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">
   <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:N} {1}">
      <Binding Path="Income"></Binding>
      <Binding ElementName="UserControl" Path="DataContext.Pinco"></Binding>
    </MultiBinding>
   </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
 </DataTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: strange.. the markup was invisible :D

Comment: you must not have had it indented correctly

Comment: What do you mean by "syntetic syntax"?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: for saying: TextAlign="right",  StringFormat="{}{0:N} {1} + DataContext.Pinco" I need 14 lines... it's not very readable. In CSS I can do the same in a more synthetic way. And the existance of classes is to avoid code repetitions. Here I have to duplicate the code for **every** column!!! :O

Answer (score 5):

XAML is XAML - I'm not sure what the meaning of "syntetic" is in this context, but the only thing I can see that could improve, is the closing tags for `<Binding>` - the empty elements can be collapsed:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:N} {1}">
  <Binding Path="Income" />
  <Binding ElementName="UserControl" Path="DataContext.Pinco" />
</MultiBinding>
```

There aren't 20 different ways of specifying the horizontal alignment of a `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">
```

I don't see anything wrong with this.

---

Actually the indentation could use more spaces, too - but that's *cosmetic* (and probably just a copy/paste glitch with the tabs):

```
<GridViewColumn Header="trial" Width="110">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:N} {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Income" />
                        <Binding ElementName="UserControl" Path="DataContext.Pinco" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>

        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I like using vertical whitespace to separate things - it makes the markup easier to read, and maintain.

---

**EDIT**: Considering that there would be 20x such markup, with the only thing changing being the `<Binding Path="Income" />` part, as @GeorgeHowarth commented you can look into making the `DataTemplate` a `StaticResource`, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8359117/1188513).

Comment: To eliminate all verbosity I guess you could define the `DataTemplate` as a XAML resource. Maybe it's worth adding in the answer as an alternative option.

Comment: @GeorgeHowarth: yes, I guess I'm looking for something similar..

Comment: You know when people refactor some similar c# method? the DRY principle? Avoid code duplication.. this is what I mean... an alternative to avoid this verbosity for defining 20 times the same identical structure of table.

Comment: @Revious If you're looking to define the `CellTemplate` as a resource [here's how you do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354650/can-i-define-celltemplate-of-datagrid-as-a-resource-so-that-it-can-be-reused-in).

Comment: @Revious the markup you have posted doesn't show 20 times the same identical structure...

Comment: @Mat'sMug: sorrym I've added an explanation to clarify that the same structure is shared by many columns.

Comment: @GeorgeHowarth: mmm... how should I do it in my example? I can't understand from the linked example sorry... can you help me?

Comment: @Mat'sMug: can you help me at understanding how to use that example with my code?